# OSGi: Java 8 default or static interface methods access produce NoSuchMethodError

Tags: osgi, java-8, aem, apache-felix

In Apache Felix OSGi environment (AEM6 SP2) any call to default or static interface method throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError.

I was able to find the method's signature in the compiled interface .class file but in runtime the method is not accessible.

Lambdas and streams work fine proofing that JRE is 8.

```
getClass().getInterfaces()[0].getMethods()
```

also doesn't list the method.

```
org.apache.felix.scr-1.8.2 
bndlib-1.43.0
```

Is it environment limitation or possible to fix?

Comment: How do you get the instance that you want to call the method on? Do you use any technology that might does proxying with ASM, Javassist or any other similar tool? Is any technology that does weaving in your OSGi container (like aries-proxy)?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you really run your framework using Java 8 it looks like you run it with an older runtime.